# AWS service to deploy a machine with default security groups, alarms, etc.?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, deployment

I am looking to provide my software setup to others for use on AWS with as few manual steps as possible. I can create an AMI with my software pre-installed and configured rather than just an installer which cuts out several issues (badly sized disks, people picking wrong/unsupported distro for my compiled binary, etc.) but this does not bundle the config for network interfaces, alarms, or other related Amazon services.

Does Amazon have a service/mechanism that will such features? I know of launch templates but these are per-region, per-account and need to be created after groups etc. have been added manually.

I know Amazon have API's for all this, but before turning to third parties or my own script I want to be sure that Amazon has no portable template type thing that can be provided and they simply launched in the console.

Comment: You can create your AMI with your software pre-installed and publish them to all the available regions(AWS marketplace/ public access). Later use Cloud formation template which will include creation of aws resources needed for your application to run including launching instance using your AMI id's for each region and the instance launch uses the ami from the corresponding region. This way your customers can just use the cloudformation template and all prerequisites will be met

Comment: @Rajesh I spent some time looking at CloudFormation and I think that is the right service/answer if you post it. It looks like it doesn't get the AMI to the region automatically, but that is a recurring thing anyway and covers most things Id want an "installation script" for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create your AMI with your software pre-installed and publish them to all the available regions(AWS marketplace/ public access).

Later use Cloud formation template which will include creation of aws resources needed for your application to run including launching instance using your AMI id's for each region and the instance launch uses the ami from the corresponding region. This way your customers can just use the cloudformation template and all prerequisites will be met.

In terms of having your AMI ID in the cloud formation template and using it based on the region in which it is launched can be achieved using the [Mappings](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/mappings-section-structure.html) section in Cloud formation. Hope that helps